# How do I run unit tests on my Python code in Buildout?

Tags: python, unit-testing, buildout

I have a Python project which is managed by zc.buildout.

My `buildout.cfg` file looks like this:

```
[buildout]
parts = python ipython
develop = .
eggs = redditsubscraper
versions = versions

[versions]

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[ipython]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg:scripts
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
    ipython
scripts = ipython
```

I'd like to add a `bin/test` script for running unit tests on my library.

How can I add this script? Is there a recipe that I need which will enable me to run `bin/test` and have my unit tests run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it.

Add a new section to `buildout.cfg`:

```
[test]
recipe = pbp.recipe.noserunner
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
    pbp.recipe.noserunner
script = test
```

Add that section to your `buildout:parts`:

```
[buildout]
parts = python ipython test
# ...
```

Run `bin/buildout` and you'll get a script called `test` in the `bin/` folder. Run that script to run all tests in your project.